# Can you determine the size of a generic type?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to get `sizeof()` a generic type? e.g.

```
public int GetSize<T>()
{
    return sizeof(T); //this wont work because T isn't assigned but is there a way to do this
}
```

As said in the example, the above is not possible, but is there a way to make it work? Tried doing `public unsafe int` but it didn't change anything. Really don't want to do something like

```
public int GetSize<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte) || typeof(T) == typeof(sbyte))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(short) || typeof(T) == typeof(ushort) || typeof(T) == typeof(char))
    {
        return 2;
    }
    //and so on.
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @mjwills making a `ReadMemory` method which read a open process's memory, i made it so its its possible to read a array of any type `public void ReadMemory<T>(IntPtr addr, T[] buffer)` i need the `sizeof(T)` so i can increase the address by the size, so if `T = int` then it would do with each count `addr = new IntPtr(addr.ToInt64() + 4)` now i dont want to do it this way, i wanted to do it like this `addr = new IntPtr(addr.ToInt64() + sizeof(T))`.

Comment: If your intent is to go into unmanaged space then take a look at https://ericlippert.com/2013/06/13/whats-the-difference-sizeof-and-marshal-sizeof/

Comment: 100% agree with @mjwills: if you need to do this then you are probably doing something wrong. Do you have an XY problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
```

Be very aware this is going to throw all sorts of unexpected results if you abuse it.

Maybe, you you could make the constraints on your generic method  limit to `Types` that will make sense to you, i.e `int`, `long` , etc.

Also be wary of things like this `Marshal.SizeoOf(typeof(char)) == 1.`

**Update**

As *MickD* posted in his comments, (and unsurprisingly) the compiler Wizard *Eric Lippert* has made a blog post on some of the finer points

[What’s the difference? sizeof and Marshal.SizeOf](https://ericlippert.com/2013/06/13/whats-the-difference-sizeof-and-marshal-sizeof/)

**Update**

Also, as pointed out by *MickD* and to make it clear for any young Jedi reading this `Marshal.SizeOf` returns unmanaged size.

[Marshal.SizeOf Method (Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the size of an unmanaged type in bytes.
>
> The size returned is the size of the unmanaged type. The unmanaged and
> managed sizes of an object can differ. For character types, the size
> is affected by the CharSet value applied to that class.

Comment: You might just want to say that `Marshal.SizeOf` returns the _unmanaged_ size :)